# Angular is intercepting requests meant for the backend

Tags: angular

I have an issue where requests should be hitting the backed are actually being interpreted by Angular (routing?). To demonstrate, when launching the VS project, the 'launching SPA proxy splash screen' is displayed. Navigating to /api/locations hits the backend as intended, **UNTIL** the Angular app is fully launched, at which point the request no longer hits the backend. I am using the solution template that comes with VS2022

[image]

[image]

Once the SPA proxy has loaded, the same request to a backend resource is handled differently (see below now returns a 304 redirect)

[image]

which returns the Angular app

[image]

Routing setup -

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
  { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
], { enableTracing: true, useHash: false })
```

Question -
I have multiple controllers in my solution, how can I stop Angular interfering with them and allow requests to hit the backend?

Comment: The request is still going to the backend (which returns the 304). So your issue seems to be backend related?

Answer (score 0):

With credit to this article here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-create-spa-with-net-6-0-and-angular-13-and-deploy-to-azure/, it is necessary to add routes into the 'context' section in proxy.conf.js as below

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
context: [
  "/weatherforecast",
  "/analytics",
  "/test",
],
target: target,
secure: false,
headers: {
  Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
}
}]
```